# Missing libraries on compiled gtkmm program on windows (MSYS2)

Tags: winapi, gtk, mingw, gtkmm, msys2

after numerous issues I finally have succeeded in compiling (Using \mingw64\bin\g++) my program that uses GTK+ 3 (gtkmm3) on windows.

However, trying to run the .exe file now fails and it complains about the following missing libraries:

```
libstdc++-6.dll
libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
libatkmm-1.6.1.dll
```

I guess something about my path may be wrong? However I dont really know what to do as I didnt face something like this before. I would appreciate any help and I am willing to provide any information that may be neccessary to resolve it^^

Edit: I know I could just download or locate these libraries to make the program run, but I would like to know why it can't seem to find them as they belong to gtkmm (at least thats true for libatkmm-1.6.1.dll)

Comment: I have fixed libstddc++ and libgcc by adding  -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ to the compile command. Now, more libraries are reported missing.

Comment: The fix to the issue is to deploy your dependencies alongside the application. Statically linking against libraries works around the issue, but is not in general a solution. Besides, libstdc++ is part of the compiler, not the toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself... I have added in my case C:\msys64\mingw64\bin to my PATH variable. But now I face my program immediately closing after opening it. Well I guess the challenge continues ;)

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? My question was about GETTING the app to RUN, not DEPLOYING it...

Comment: Thanks a lot! As for getting the window to work, try this: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en