# GTKMM - Error compiling the hello world example

Tags: c++, windows, msys2, gtkmm4

I am trying to build the hello world gtkmm example from the docs using the command

```
    -DLIBDEFLATE_DLL -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtkmm-4.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gtkmm-4.0/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-4.0 \
    -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/cairo -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/graphene-1.0 \
    -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/graphene-1.0/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/pangomm-2.48 \
    -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/pangomm-2.48/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/giomm-2.68 \
    -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/giomm-2.68/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/glibmm-2.68 \
    -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/glibmm-2.68/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/cairomm-1.16 \
    -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/cairomm-1.16/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/sigc++-3.0 \
    -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/sigc++-3.0/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/pango-1.0 \
    -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/harfbuzz -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/pango-1.0 \
    -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/fribidi -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/cairo \
    -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/freetype2 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/harfbuzz \
    -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/pixman-1 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 \
    -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/libpng16 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/webp \
    -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include \
    -lgtkmm-4.0 -lgtk-4.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lgraphene-1.0 -lpangomm-2.48 \
    -lgiomm-2.68 -lgio-2.0 -lglibmm-2.68 -lcairomm-1.16 -lsigc-3.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 \
    -lharfbuzz -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

or

```
g++ -static -static-libgcc `pkg-config gtkmm-4 --cflags --libs`
```

this resutls in the following errors

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgtk-4: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgraphene-1.0: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53470836/missing-libraries-on-compiled-gtkmm-program-on-windows-msys2) I should add the path `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` so i did but it did not help

I am using msys2 to compile this example

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

class Win : public Gtk::Window
{
    public:
        Win();
};

Win::Win()
{
    set_title("Hello world");
    set_default_size(500,500);
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create("org.gtkmm.examples.base");
    return app->make_window_and_run<Win>(argc, argv);
}
```

I did verify that `gtk-4` and  `graphene` are both installed and located the `include` and `lib` folders

Comment: Can you show the content of `lib`, and the full path to it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat here is the path of lib folder `/c/msys64/mingw64/lib` and here is the full contents of the [lib folder](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/loadeddypper/7bb9c938a6a0452b1d73d99af370855a/raw/f602daafc41635124057ae89a5fb1c792e4c0524/gistfile1.txt)

Comment: Looks good. 1. Are you sure the command you show us is what it actually is? 2. What terminal/shell are you running this from? Any modified env variables?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i created a [repo](https://github.com/loadeddypper/gtkmm4/blob/main/README.md) with the source code and the `makefile` and a screenshot for the bash terminal in msys2